# How to add a custom resolution? xrandr fails

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I am well aware that this question has been asked multiple times, but no solution has worked for me.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I got the modeline with `cvt`, added a new mode with `xrandr --newmode`, checked the name of the monitor in question with `xrandr--listmonitors`, and then attempted to add the mode to my monitor. Here's the command and output:

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

I have not been able to find a solution that works.
I am using two monitors - an HDMI one and a DVI one. The HDMI one works well and its native resolution is properly displayed as an option. The second monitor is DVI, and I can't use its native resolution no matter what I try.

The video card is Nvidia GTX770 with the latest proprietary driver.

Here's the complete set of commands I used and their outputs:

```
gshpychka@DeepLearningMachine:~$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
gshpychka@DeepLearningMachine:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
gshpychka@DeepLearningMachine:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*HDMI-0 2560/673x1080/284+720+0  HDMI-0
 1: +DVI-I-0 720/190x1280/339+0+0  DVI-I-0
gshpychka@DeepLearningMachine:~$ 
gshpychka@DeepLearningMachine:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is probably the propriatary nvidia driver it has a check if modes match some monitor charateristics, for adding an abitrary mode this needs to be disabled in the X11 config, see Option "ModeValidation" in https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.12/README/appendix-b.html